# How can I install kerberised services on debian?

Tags: linux, debian, telnet, kerberos

I installed kerberos in my debian environment and made it work with SSH. I also would like to try it with other services but I could not install them on debian. I followed several tutorials e.g.

- https://www.debian-administration.org/article/570/MIT_Kerberos_installation_on_Debian (paragraph Installing Kerberized Services)
- https://itservices.stanford.edu/service/kerberos/install_debian

When I tried to run commands

```
apt-get install krb5-rsh-server
```

OR

```
apt-get install krb5-telnetd
```

I encountered on this error:

```
user@pc# apt-get install krb5-rsh-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package krb5-rsh-server
```

I am running this version of Linux (Debian): Debian 3.16.3-2 (2014-09-20) x86_64 GNU/Linux

Do I need to install some other package to be able to install kerberized services?

Can anyone help me to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can´t install the package as a user. Try

```
sudo apt-get install krb5-rsh-server
```

Comment: The OP shows `#` as part of the prompt, indicating that they are almost certainly using the root account to attempt the `apt-get`. The issue is that the package is not found, not that they can't install it.

Comment: You are right, I was mislead by the user@

Answer (score 0):

You might need to `apt-get update` to refresh your local list of packages.

Debian "wheezy" contains the [`kbr5-rsh-server` package](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/krb5-rsh-server). The package does not exist in Debian "jessie", but `rsh-redone-server` *might* be the new name (I can't tell whether or not it includes Kerberised code).

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I will check rsh-redone-server out. I also asked the same question on another forum and they answered me that such services like rsh, telnetd were removed from jessie.

Comment: @mark thank you for that update; it's useful information